# Отправка уведомлений клиенту с сервера Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, sse

Есть небольшое приложение.

На сервере выполняются несколько методов, в ходе выполнения которых необходимо клиенту выводить различные уведомления.

Понял что есть `Websocket`-ы и `Server Sent Event`. 
Что из них предпочтительнее использовать или может быть есть другие возможности?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Коротко

Если нужно

- не только отправлять данные с сервера в браузер, но и с браузера в сервер по тому же каналу
- отправлять не только текстовые форматы данных, но и бинарные
- ограничение на количество подключений недопустимо

то нужно использовать **вебсокеты**

Если нужно

- работать в корпоративных сетых
- можно ограничиться только связью сервер -> клиент
- нужно использовать только стандартный протокол HTTP

то можно использовать SSE

---

#### Подробнее

Вебсокеты позволяют как получать в браузере данные с сервера так и отправлять их.

SSE(Server Sent Events) в свою очередь помогают только отправлять данные с сервера в браузер.

**Преимущества SSE над вебсокетами:**

- Передается по стандартному HTTP протоколу
- Может быть подхвачен JavaScript'ом в браузерах с отсутствующей поддержкой SSE
- Встроенная поддержка переподключения и определения события
- Более простой протокол
- Нет проблем с корпоративными фаерволами

**Преимущества вебсокетов над SSE:**

- Двунаправленная связь в режиме реального времени
- Нативная поддержка в большинстве браузеров
- Передача бинарных данных

**Наиболее подходящим пример использования вебсокетов:**

- Онлайн-чат.

**Наиболее подходящие примеры использования SSE:**

- Потоковая передача изменений биржевых котировок
- Обновление ленты Твиттера
- Уведомления в браузере

**Недостатки SSE:**

- Нет поддержки бинарных данных
- Имеется ограничение на максимальное число подключений

---

**Ограничение на количество подключений SSE:**

SSE имеет ограничение на максимальное число подключений со стороны клиента.
Данное ограничение может быть особенно неприятным, потому что оно очень маленькое (максимум 6 подключений одновременно), что может вызывать проблемы при открытии множество вкладок одного и того же сервиса.
При этом данная проблема в Chrome и Firefox отмечена как "Won't fix", что говорит о том, что данное обстоятельство в будущем никак не изменится к лучшему.
Ограничение распространяется на связку `<Браузер> + <Домен>`, поэтому его можно обойти используя разные доменные имена. Например: 6 подключений к домену `test1.ru` и 6 подключений к домену `test2.ru`

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если использование в Spring MVC приложении SSE это нормальная практика, то у меня возникли две трудности при реализации вывода уведомлений через SSE. 1. То что русские буквы выводятся как знаки ?? и второе иногда приложение выдает ошибку пишет "Выброшено исключение java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение" Происходит это в том месте, где я в методах вывожу сообщение таким образом SetNotification("Сообщение").. Такая ошибка бывает не всегда.

Comment: @SergeyMih я постараюсь сегодня на примере конкретного проекта посмотреть и сегодня или завтра ответить

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.